# Controlling the output window in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Every time i compile or run, the flex builder opens a browser showing the output... is there anyway we can destory the older window when newer ones open... i mean a setting in flex.

Answer (score 0):

no. but i think if your pressing debug test and that opens a new browser and starts debugging your app, when you hit stop on the debugging, the app will terminate and close the browser as well. this if the debugging app is the only tab you have opened in the browser. other than that, you can't really do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flex builder set up to build automatically then you just need to save the file that you have changed and then when flex have finished building (you can see the status down in the right corner of the screen) reload your browser.
That is pretty much the workflow i have when i develop in flex. This way i only get new browser windows opened when i debug.